# want to change the color of image dynamically using jquery canvas

Tags: jquery, html, image, canvas

I am trying to change the color of the image using slider and canvas
but unable to get the converted image. By sliding the slider the `r, g, b` values are obtained and it is passed to `colorchanger()` function and there the value is given to the pixel of the image. When I call the `colorchanger()` function from the `refreshSwatch` function the slider stops working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Slider - Colorpicker</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
    />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
      #red,
      #green,
      #blue {
        float: left;
        clear: left;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 15px;
      }
      #swatch {
        width: 120px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-top: 18px;
        margin-left: 350px;
        background-image: none;
      }
      #red .ui-slider-range {
        background: #ef2929;
      }
      #red .ui-slider-handle {
        border-color: #ef2929;
      }
      #green .ui-slider-range {
        background: #8ae234;
      }
      #green .ui-slider-handle {
        border-color: #8ae234;
      }
      #blue .ui-slider-range {
        background: #729fcf;
      }
      #blue .ui-slider-handle {
        border-color: #729fcf;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        function hexFromRGB(r, g, b) {
          var hex = [r.toString(16), g.toString(16), b.toString(16)];
          $.each(hex, function (nr, val) {
            if (val.length === 1) {
              hex[nr] = '0' + val;
            }
          });

          ctx.drawImage(imgData, 0, 0);
          return hex.join('').toUpperCase();
        }
        function refreshSwatch() {
          (red = $('#red').slider('value')),
            (green = $('#green').slider('value')),
            (blue = $('#blue').slider('value'));
          var hex = hexFromRGB(red, green, blue);
          colorchanger(red, green, blue);
          $('#swatch').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
        }

        var red, green, blue;
        var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        var img = document.getElementById('scream');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

        function colorchanger(r, g, b) {
          for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
            imgData.data[i] = imgData.data[i] + r;
            imgData.data[i + 1] = imgData.data[i + 1] + g;
            imgData.data[i + 2] = imgData.data[i + 2] + b;
            imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
          }
          ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
          return;
        }

        $('#red, #green, #blue').slider({
          orientation: 'horizontal',
          range: 'min',
          max: 255,
          value: 127,
          slide: refreshSwatch,
          change: refreshSwatch,
        });

        $('#red').slider('value', 255);
        $('#green').slider('value', 140);
        $('#blue').slider('value', 60);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="ui-widget-content" style="border:0;">
    <p
      class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"
      style="padding:4px;"
    >
      <span
        class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"
        style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"
      ></span>
    </p>

    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>

    <div id="swatch" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>

    <img
      id="scream"
      src="pics/editedshirt.png"
      alt="The Scream"
      width="220"
      height="277"
    />
    <canvas
      id="myCanvas"
      width="220"
      height="277"
      style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"
    >
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```